# SuiteScript 2.0: How do you load a dataset and then add conditions?

Tags: dataset, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

The situation:
I am trying to load a dataset and then add additional criteria (filters) to the dataset based off users selected fields. The whole dev is a "Custom Report" build using a suitlete that has some fields the user can populate to choose "dynamic filters". When they click on the generate button I add the criteria/filters to a search and dataset and then join the results and display them.

The issue is that while I am able to add filters to the search after I load it no matter what I try I can't seem to add filters to the Dataset.

This code gets the dataset Data:

```
var datasetData = datasetLib.load({ id: datasetId });

resultSet.pageRanges.forEach(function (pageRange) {

    // Fetch the results on the current page
    var myPage = resultSet.fetch({ index: pageRange.index });
    res.data = res.data.concat(myPage.data.results);

    if (res.columns.length < 1) {
        var columns = JSON.parse(myPage.pagedData.queryDefinition).columns;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            res.columns.push(columns[i].label);

        }
    }

});
```

I attempted many different iterations to create the condition... here is one:

```
dataset.createCondition({
    column: datasetData.columns[0], // I loaded the dataset and use it to reference the column
    operator: query.Operator.ANY_OF,
    values: params.customer.split(',')
})
```

Now the above code DOSE create a condition but when I attempt to add it into the dataset's current conditions I receive errors.I am attempting to push it into the child parameter of the parent criteria.

Please ask if you need more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a workbook is fine then I would suggest you to load the workbook using your above dataset using the query module and then use the above createCondition to add the condition to the loaded query dynamically.

```
    var myLoadedQuery = query.load({
        id: 'custworkbook237'
    });

    var mySalesRepJoin = myLoadedQuery.autoJoin({
        fieldId: 'salesrep'
    });

    var thirdCondition = mySalesRepJoin.createCondition({
        fieldId: 'email,
        operator: query.Operator.START_WITH_NOT,
        values: 'foo'
    });
```

I would also urge to ensure the joins are accurately represented by looking at the Records catalog via Setup>Records Catalog. Hope this helps.